# LaTeX book template dependent files

Tags: books, overleaf

Does anyone know how to obtain all dependent files to properly compile a book such as: https://www.overleaf.com/articles/clustering-the-interstellar-medium/mtthgyyfrdkn#.VdEz6HibgbA

To be clear, I'm trying to compile this book on my own computer (not Overleaf), yet I lack the auxiliary style files that accompany this template, which Overleaf seems to not provide.

Also, as a peripheral question: is there a way to make this template be 6x9?  Not every available template online is preconfigured to 6x9 settings, so I'm wondering if this is possible to configure yourself within the source?

Comment: Overleaf *does* indeed provide *all* necesary files: go to https://www.overleaf.com/3103279bymtgy#/8631847/ To the left, click on Download as ZIP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overleaf *does* indeed provide *all* necesary files: go to https://www.overleaf.com/3103279bymtgy#/8631847/ Here's a screenshot of the page:

[image]

To the left, click on "Download as ZIP". This will download a folder containing `main.tex`, `structure.tex`, `StyleInd.ist` and a `Pictures` folder with all necessary images. Process `main.tex` and you'll get a 27 pages document (and lots of warnings).

Comment: @warship Sure. Screenshot added.