# Adding Cyrillic in LaTeX templates

Tags: templates, cyrillic

I am trying to configure Cyrillic (namely, the Russian language) in my LaTeX template.  I successfully downloaded the template like this: [LaTeX book template dependent files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261691/latex-book-template-dependent-files/261692?noredirect=1#comment627489_261692)

The only change that I made to the template was in the `main.tex` file, which I'm showing the snippet of code below:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations

    \usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry} % Page margins

    \usepackage{fontspec} % loaded by polyglossia, but included here for transparency 
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{english} 
    \setotherlanguage{russian}

    %\newfontfamily\russianfont[Script=Cyrillic]{Linux Libertine}

    \usepackage{xcolor} % Required for specifying colors by name
    \definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{52,177,201} % Define the orange color used for highlighting throughout the book

    % Font Settings
    \usepackage{avant} % Use the Avantgarde font for headings
    %\usepackage{times} % Use the Times font for headings
    \usepackage{mathptmx} % Use the Adobe Times Roman as the default text font together with math symbols from the SymÂ­bol, Chancery and ComÂ­puter Modern fonts

    \usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs

    % Bibliography
    \usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file
    \defbibheading{bibempty}{}

    \input{structure} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template

    \begin{document}

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   TITLE PAGE
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \begingroup
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,0){\includegraphics[scale=1.25]{esahubble}}} % Image background
    \centering
    \vspace*{5cm}
    \par\normalfont\fontsize{35}{35}\sffamily\selectfont

    \textbf{Привет}\\


    {\LARGE Data Mining and Machine Learning in Astronomy}\par % Book title
    \vspace*{1cm}
    {\Huge Andrea Hidalgo}\par % Author name
    \endgroup
```

As you can see, I've added one Russian word at the bottom of the file and attempted setting up Russian at the top of the file.  I have tried these options so far: [How to include russian in LaTeX (LEd)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112371/how-to-include-russian-in-latex-led) and [Cyrillic in (La)TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/816/cyrillic-in-latex).  I have tried a few different options from these two existing questions.

I seem to be running into an issue with `babel`, something along these lines: [babel with russian and english language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50635/babel-with-russian-and-english-language).  Specifically, the compiler doesn't like this specific line in my `structure.tex` file: `\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation`.  I have tried specifying `russian` inside its scope, but that doesn't solve my issue.

Can anyone please help me configure Russian for my template?  I don't understand why none of those options have worked for me (yet).

**EDIT**

Another MWE using suggestions provided from here: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Russian

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry} % Page margins

\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for specifying colors by name
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{52,177,201} % Define the orange color used for highlighting throughout the book

% Font Settings
\usepackage{avant} % Use the Avantgarde font for headings
%\usepackage{times} % Use the Times font for headings
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Use the Adobe Times Roman as the default text font together with math symbols from the SymÂ­bol, Chancery and ComÂ­puter Modern fonts

\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs

\usepackage[russian]{babel}

% Bibliography
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

\input{structure} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template
```

Comment: You say you use LaTeX, but since you load the fontspec package I assume you are using XeLaTeX. Correct?

Comment: You are extending a template meant for `pdflatex` with commands and packages meant for `xelatex`. This won't work. Instead of trying to adapt a large template you should better start with small examples and learn the differences between the engines.

Comment: @ph0t0nix Yes, in the MWE I'm showing above, I'm using XeLaTeX.  However, I also tried some other approaches, as outlined in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/816/cyrillic-in-latex.  But, so far, none of these approaches worked for me, which makes me wonder what is fundamentally different between my problem and the others.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Correct, I am using XeLaTeX for the template above.  See my other comment to ph0t0nix.  Following your advice, I've tried each small example as per each different approach presented in tex.stackexchange.com/questions/816/cyrillic-in-latex, but nothing worked for me.  It seems that I am dealing with a scenario fundamentally different than the ones already asked about on tex.stackexchange.

Comment: @warship: And as I said: It won't work. The template is not for xelatex. You will have to remove inputenc, avant, mathptmx, fontenc and perhaps some more lines and packages in the structure.tex to adapt it to xelatex. Don't use large templates that you don't understand. If you have a problem with a small example then show this example and the error messages you get.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It looks like many of the things you mentioned work just fine "out of the box": https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Russian

Comment: The first template is completely wrong; the second one is good, but there's no support for the T2A encoding with `avant` and `mathptmx`.

Comment: @egreg I see.  So I guess my only option is to choose another (hopefully simpler) template?

Comment: Is there any news here?